# Maven and Jenkinsfile - skipping previous phases

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm exploring Jenkins staging functionality and I want to devise a fast and lean setup.

Basically, Jenkins promotes the use of stages to partition in the build process and provide nice visual feedback about the progress of the build.

So the `Jenkinsfile` goes something like

```
stage("Build")
bat("mvn compile")

stage("Test")
bat("mvn test")

stage("Deploy")
bat("mvn deploy")
```

This works well, but feels wrong, because `deploy` and `test` will both do activities from previous phases again.

As a result, in this setup I am building three times (although skipping compilation due to no changes) and testing two times (in the test and the deploy runs).

When I google around I can find various switches and one of them works for skipping unit tests, but the compilation and dependency resolution steps happen regardless of what I do.

Do I need to choose between speed and stages in this case or can I have both?

I mean:

```
stage("Resolve dependencies, build, test and deploy")
bat("mvn deploy")
```

is by far the fastest approach, but it doesn't produce a nice progress table in Jenkins.

Comment: You can create a [custom maven lifecycle](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLifecycleInMaven)

Comment: Use `-DskipTests` to skip the tests in the _deploy_ stage. That your application is already compiled should be automatically detected.

Answer (score 1):

In order to bring incremental builds in Maven phases as Gradle does, you can use [takari-lifecycle](https://github.com/takari/takari-lifecycle) maven plugin.

So, once the plugin is apply you will get all the benefits. In your example, `Test` stage which will perform `mvn test` will avoid compilation because it was compiled in the previous stage and `Deploy` stage will avoid compilation from your main source code and test source code but tests will be executed again so I suggest to add `-DskipTests`.

Comment: i just came across this and was curious about takari-lifecycle plugin.  unfortunately it looks like it is no longer supported (no updates since 2015)